# Find the right path with os.chdir() in digital ocean

Tags: python, terminal, chdir

I tried several ways but never succeeded. I need to change the directory in digital ocean (`/home/vagrant`). I have files saved in the same folder as where the file.py file is. file.py and other files that file.py aims to execute are all in `/folder/PH/Programs`. When I ran `$python file.py`, it appeared an error of the directory:

```
os.chdir('/folder/PH/Programs')


OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   '/folder/PH/Programs'
```

Comment: The directory you've asked for (`/folder/PH/Programs`) doesn't exist. In which folder is `file.py`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I edited my question. file.py is in `folder/PH/Programs`. Should I have something like 'i: ~/folder/PH/Programs'?

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh Yeah, it should start from the home directory. Try with `~/folder`. It worked, right?

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh I think you are confusing yourself. The directory with the slash before "folder" does not exist, and is in fact the cause of your error. How can it work now?

Comment: Yes, @super_cr7, ~/folder works, and the full path suggested by J.C. Rocamonde works, too. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you provide the full path to file, or do not put a slash at the beginning. That means the root directory.

go with:

```
os.chdir('~/folder/PH/Programs')
```

If it is in your home directory, or otherwise specify the full path to file.

(In fact, the path you say in your question is wrong for the same reason).